Find total ways such that Mr. A’s $3$ digit number is greater than Mr. B’s $3$ digit number:
If Mr. A randomly picks $3$ distinct numberrs from the set $\{1,2,3,....,9\}$ and arranges
them in descending order to form a three digit number, and Mr.B randomly picks $3$
distinct numbers from the set $\{1,2,3,....,8\}$ and also arranges them in descending order
to form a three digit number. Then find total ways such that Mr. A’s $3$ digit number is
greater than Mr. B’s $3$ digit number:
My Answer: Case $1$: Mr. A. picks $9$ as one of the digit then Mr.A's $3$ digit number is always Mr. B's $3$ digit number so total ways are ${8\choose2}\cdot{8\choose 3}$
Note: Mr. A picks two other digit other than $9$ and Mr. B picks any $3$ digit number from set $\{1,2,3,....,8\}$
Case $2$: Mr. A does not pick digit $9$ in this case there are total $\dfrac{{8\choose 3}^2-{8\choose 3}}{2}$
So final Answer is ${8\choose2}\cdot{8\choose 3}+\biggl[\dfrac{{8\choose 3}^2-{8\choose 3}}{2}\biggl]$
But given answer is ${8\choose 2}+\bigg[\dfrac{{8\choose 3}^2-{8\choose 3}}{2}\bigg]$
I want to confirm that is my answer correct?

You are correct.  I think the official solution  left the second factor off by accident

Yes, your answer is correct.  The "given answer" forgot that when A has picked a $9$ and thus guaranteed his number is greater, B still has to pick.
